# Dynamically added Images do not call Load Function

Tags: jquery

Any ideas why this works:

```
$(document).on('click', '.vpImg', function(){console.log("CLICKED")});
```

But this does not work:

```
$(document).on('load', '.vpImg',  function(){console.log("LOADED")});
```

Where `.vpImg` and dynamically created `img` tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [jQuery API Docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/),

> In all browsers, the load, scroll, and error events (e.g., on an img
>   element) do not bubble. In Internet Explorer 8 and lower, the paste
>   and reset events do not bubble. Such events are not supported for use
>   with delegation, but they can be used when the event handler is
>   directly attached to the element generating the event.